# Show that the image of a closed set is closed given that f is continuous and the preimage of a compact set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and has the additional property that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact whenever $K$ is compact. Show that $f(C)$ is closed whenever $C$ is closed.

I have spent many hours on this problem and the furthest I have gotten is:

We want to show that $f(C)$ is closed by showing $\mathbb{R}\setminus f(C)$ is open. That is we want to show $y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus f(C)$ is an interior point. We know that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $I = [y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon]$ is compact. Then by the property above, $f^{-1}(I)$ is compact.

Any hints on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{f(c_n)\}$ be a sequence in $f(C)$ converging to some point $y$. We have to show that $y \in f(C)$. Let $K=\{y,f(c_1),f(c_2),\cdots \}$. Then $K$ is a compact set and hence $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact. Also, $\{c_n\} \subset f^{-1}(K)$. Hence there is a subseqeunce $c_{n_k}$ conveging to some limit $x$. Since $C$ is closed, $x \in C$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(c_{n_k}) \to f(x)$. But then $y=f(x)$. Hence $y \in F(C)$ as required.